# PEAR DB Connect On A Different Port

Tags: php, mysql, pear

I am trying to connect a the PEAR DB class to a MySQL server operating on a different port.

Code:

```
$db =& DB::connect(mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3307/rfq);
```

The reason for connecting to 127.0.0.1 on 3307 is that I am actually SSH tunneling into a different server.

However I just get the error DB Error: not found

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: after the ip, try adding port:3307

Comment: mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1port:3307 wont work - the database connection should work as I can access via mysql -uuser -ppasword -h127.0.0.1 -P3307

Comment: Run the debug from PEAR gettings this error: Unable to include the DB/.php file for '' however the '' is blank and so is the filename before .php